# Laravel - Fatal error: Trait method subscription has not been applied

Tags: php, laravel, traits

here is a code scenario I am facing and I tried to solve it by providing a name for my class for trait methods but the problem is still there. what should I do?

```
trait Billable{
    public function subscription(){
    }
}
trait Plan{
    public function subscription(){
    }
}
class User {
    use Billable, Plan{
        Billable::subscription as public billAbleSubscription;
        Plan::subscription as public planAbleSubscription;
    }
}
$obj = new User();
```

I want to a user both methods the same name but different functionality. is there any way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflict.  You can use PHP [Conflict Resolution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict):

> If two Traits insert a method with the same name, a fatal error is produced, if the conflict is not explicitly resolved.
>
> To resolve naming conflicts between Traits used in the same class, the
>   insteadof operator needs to be used to choose exactly one of the
>   conflicting methods.

The manual gives a bit of a convoluted example using the `insteadof` operator and THEN an alias using the `as` operator as you had tried above, as copied below:

```
trait A {
public function smallTalk() {
    echo 'a';
}
public function bigTalk() {
    echo 'A';
}
}

trait B {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'b';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    }
}

class Aliased_Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;

        B::bigTalk as talk;       // <------
    }
}
```

I think you were almost there, and frankly yours looks totally logical to me, but perhaps the syntax needs to include the `insteadof` operator and a bit more code as in the above example.  Try this - HTH

Answer (score 0):

we have to give names to each conflict method and we have to define that if we will invoke method by its original name then method from which trait will be called. so here is complete solved code.

```
trait Billable{

    public function subscription(){

        echo "billable subscription. 
";
    }
}

trait Plan{
    public function subscription(){

        echo "plan subscription. 
";

    }

}

class User {

    use Billable, Plan{

        Billable::subscription as public billAbleSubscription;
        Plan::subscription insteadof Billable;
        Plan::subscription as public planAbleSubscription;

    }
}

$obj = new User();

$obj->billAbleSubscription();
$obj->planAbleSubscription();
$obj->subscription();
```